# Error TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

tengo el siguiente código en Python 3 en el que se pretende pasar los argumentos como parametros a las funciones y el resultado se devuelve en un return

El codigo que tengo es

```
def factura_energia(numeroDeSuscriptor, cargoBasico, kwSubsidiados, cargoPorKwExtra, kwConsumidos)-> str:
    codigo_cliente = str['numeroDeSuscriptor']
    valor_cargo_basico = int['cargoBasico']
    kw_subsidiados = int['kwSubsidiados']
    cargo_kw_extra = int['cargoPorkwExtra']
    kw_consumidos = int['kwConsumidos']
   
   
    numeroDeSuscriptor = str()
    kwConsumidos = int()
    kwSubsidiados = int()
    cargoPorkwExtra = int()
    cargoBasico = int()
    totalFactura = int()
    
    subtotal = (kwConsumidos - kwSubsidiados) * cargoPorkwExtra + cargoBasico

    iva = subtotal * 0.19
    valor_total = subtotal + iva
    valor_total = totalFactura
     
    
    factura_energia(30000,200,400,400)
    
    
    numeroDeSuscriptor = str(input())
    cargoBasico = int(input())
    kwSubsidiados = int(input())
    cargoPorkwExtra = int(input())
    kwConsumidos = int(input())
    valor_total = float(totalFactura)

    
    return f"El cliente {numeroDeSuscriptor} debe cancelar: {totalFactura} pesos"

factura_energia("YFC321", 30000, 200, 400, 400)
```

y me sale el siguiente error:

```
File "c:\Users\Wilson\Documents\Documents\CURSO TIC\CURSO BASICO PROGRAMACIÓN\UNIDAD 1\RETOS\reto_1.py", line 42, in <module>
    factura_energia("YFC321", 30000, 200, 400, 400)
  File "c:\Users\Wilson\Documents\Documents\CURSO TIC\CURSO BASICO PROGRAMACIÓN\UNIDAD 1\RETOS\reto_1.py", line 2, in factura_energia
    codigo_cliente = str['numeroDeSuscriptor']
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

ayuda por favor

Answer (score 0):

Formalmente, intentas acceder a un diccionario llamado `str`:

```
codigo_cliente = str['numeroDeSuscriptor']
```

`str` es el nombre de una función intrinsica y también el nombre de un tipo de dato, y desde luego, no hay ningún diccionario `str` en tu código.

En esa línea, parece que quieres hacer es convertir un parámetro numérico a string. Eso se hace con la *función* `str(valor)`.

```
codigo_cliente = str(numeroDeSuscriptor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mira tu error es sencillo pues haces mal la conversión, estas haciendo

```py
codigo_cliente = str['numeroDeSuscriptor']
```

lo cual no es correcto pues esto representa una de dos cosas, 1. estructura de una lista o 2. estructura de un diccionario, lo que Python entiende con esto, es que existe una variable `str` y quieres acceder a su elemento `numeroDeSuscriptor` lo cual no es así y aun peor `str` es una pablara reservada lo que indica que quieres acceder a un atributo del objeto `str`, lo que obviamente desencadena el error. La forma correcta seria usando paréntesis `str()`, esto convierte a string el dato que le pases. Pero aún hay algo más, tu haces:

```py
codigo_cliente = str('numeroDeSuscriptor')
print(codigo_cliente)

#salida-> numeroDeSuscriptor

valor_cargo_basico = int('cargoBasico')
print(valor_cargo_basico)

#te dará un bonito error :)
```

Esto es porque estas usando las comillas `''` y python interpreta que todo lo que esta entre comillas es un string, la forma correcta seria

```
codigo_cliente = str(numeroDeSuscriptor)
print(codigo_cliente)
#te dara lo que pases por parametro

valor_cargo_basico = int(cargoBasico)
print(valor_cargo_basico)
#te dara lo que pases por parametro
```

Bien también hay otro error en el código. pues haces

```py
numeroDeSuscriptor = str()
```

Esto crea un nuevo dato diciendo que `numeroDeSuscriptor` es de tipo string pero está sin valor, si lo que quieres es convertir el parámetro a *string* esto es completamente innecesario, pues ya lo has echo arriba.

Por otro lado no se que haces con esta linea `factura_energia(30000,200,400,400)` pues esto hará una llamada a la misma función una y otra vez por lo que te quedaras esperando *eternamente* (al final te dará un error), solución: eliminar la linea.

Para terminar, estas pidiendo un `input()` al usuario osea le estas pidiendo que ingrese algo en `numeroDeSuscriptor = str(input())` y creo que tu idea es mostrar el dato, para eso solo haz `print(numeroDeSuscriptor)` lo que mostrará el valor del dato, te mostrare como queda el código con todos las mejoras hechas.

```py
def factura_energia(numeroDeSuscriptor, cargoBasico, kwSubsidiados, cargoPorKwExtra, kwConsumidos)-> str:
    #lo metemos en un try en caso el usuario ingrese un string en vez de numero
    try:
        codigo_cliente = str(numeroDeSuscriptor)
        valor_cargo_basico = int(cargoBasico)
        kw_subsidiados = int(kwSubsidiados)
        cargo_kw_extra = int(cargoPorKwExtra)
        kw_consumidos = int(kwConsumidos)
    except:
        return "ingrese los datos correctamente"
    
    subtotal = (kw_consumidos - kw_subsidiados) * cargo_kw_extra + valor_cargo_basico

    iva = subtotal * 0.19
    valor_total = subtotal + iva
    totalFactura = valor_total 
     
    
    # factura_energia(30000,200,400,400)
    
    return f"El cliente {numeroDeSuscriptor} debe cancelar: {totalFactura} pesos"
```

**probamos**

```
factura_energia("YFC321", 30000, 200, 400, 400)
```

**salida**

```
El cliente YFC321 debe cancelar: 130900.0 pesos
```